# apache-nifi and LDAP integration error

Tags: security, authentication, ldap, apache-nifi

I have integrated apache-nifi 1.3.0 (cluster with secured i.e, https, used toolkit) with LDAP (not secured ) 
when I open NiFI UI login pages is coming but when i login with user getting below 
Unknown user with identity 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org'. Contact the system administrator.
can please help me to slve this issuse where am missing .

thanking you

Regards 
PRAMOD

Answer (score 1):

The identity you put in "Initial Admin" in authorizers.xml has to match exactly with the identity you are going to first login as.

If you are entering "admin" into the login page and LDAP is returning 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org' then your Initial Admin has to be 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org'.

If you need to change the initial admin, stop NiFi, remove users.xml and authorizations.xml, edit the initial admin, and restart and it will regenerate users.xml and authorizations.xml.